# How to trigger and download a zip from my react website

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a website built with ReactJS and I have some image data stored in Firebase storage. I want to download the images as a zip file to the user's computer by clicking on a button. How can I achieve this? I can get the urls to the images (to show it on the page), but I don't know where to start to make it so that the user can download them as a file. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: There is no built-in functionality to turn a bunch of files into a zip file. You will have to write code to accomplish that. I recommend reading some of the previous questions on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-storage%5D+download+folder+as+zip